# How to write mysql select?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that stores values for attributes associated to products.

```
row_id  product_id attribute_id  value
1   1   1   a
2   1   2   b
3   2   1   d
4   2   2   e
```

How do i write a select to get the value for attribute_id=2 only for products that have  value="a" for attribute_id=1?

Thanks,

Have a nice day

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
select * 
from your_table
where attribute_id = 2 
  and product_id in (
    select product_id 
    from your_table
    where attribute_id = 1 and value = 'a'
)
```

With your sample data the row with `row_id = 2` would be returned.